# Unable to understand the error in r function for stemming row wise data in dataframe

Tags: r, function, text-mining, stemming

I have to stem the words in strings in each of rows of a dataframe and i was trying to use a function which gave me a vague error.

First the dataframe with text:

```
sentences <- data.frame(sentences = c('walk walks walked walking walker walkers', 'Never ignore coincidence unless of course you are busy In which case always ignore coincidence'))
```

Then the function:

```
require(SnowballC)

stem_text <- function(text, language = "porter", mc.cores = 1) {

  # stem each word in a block of text
  stem_string <- function(str, language) {
    str <- strsplit(x = str, split = "\s")
    str <- wordStem(unlist(str), language = language)
    str <- paste(str, collapse = " ")
    return(str)
    }

  # stem each text block in turn
  x <- mclapply(X = text, FUN = stem_string, language, mc.cores = mc.cores)

  # return stemed text blocks
  return(unlist(x))
}
```

I was supposed to use the above function:

```
 stem_text(sentences$sentences, language = 'en', mc.cores = 2)
```

To get the result after stemming:

```
 # [1] 'walk walk walk walk walker walker';                                                
 # [2] 'Never ignor coincid unless of cours you are busi In which case alway ignor coincid'
```

But above function failed with the error:

```
 Error in unlist(x) : object 'x' not found
 > }
 Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Comment: Do you not get the error `Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string` when defining this function (before even running it)? You have an invalid string (a syntax error). Did you mean `split = "\\s"`?

Comment: A good way to debug a function is to test whether you can run the same code *without* it being a function. For example, does your `mclapply` line calling `stem_string` return `x` as you expect?

Comment: @MrFlick This worked for function, but then I got another error. `Error in strsplit(x = str, split = "\\s") : non-character argument`

Comment: Sounds like `sentences$sentences` might be a factor rather than a character value. Try passing in `as.character(sentences$sentences)` to the function instead, or read in your data without conversion to factor.

Comment: yes, you were correct. even I didn't notice that. it worked. thanks.